# Очистка массива

Tags: javascript

Массив успешно очищается, но после того, как я хочу его снова заполнить,
массив не выводит свои элементы

```js
let massive = [ 1,2,3,4,5];

massive.length = 0;

massive.length = 5;

alert(massive); // Выводит запятые, а цифр нет.
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос? В том, что удаленные значения волшебным образом не возникают снова?

Comment: Это учебное задание или в реальном коде встретилось?) Может изначально подход неверный...

Comment: `massive.length = 0;` - здесь вы удалили данные массива

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME, Это учебное задание; в реальном коде, конечно, не надо так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите тут про [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

В любой момент вы можете установить свойство `length` для обрезки массива. Когда вы расширяете массив, изменяя его свойство length, реальное количество элементов в массиве увеличивается; например, если вы установите свойство length в 3, когда оно равно 2, массив будет из 3 элементов, где значение третьего элемента будет равно **undefined**.

```
let massive = [ 1,2,3,4,5];

massive.length = 0; // обрезали массив

massive.length = 5; // увеличили массив, элементы соответственно undefined

alert(massive); // Выводит запятые, а цифр нет.
```

Думаю после того как элементы стали `undefined` нужно заполнить массив приемлемым для вас способом, благо способов много.

Пример из комментариев

```js
 let massive = [ 1,2,3,4,5]; 
 massive.length = 0; 
 massive = [ 1,2,3,4,5]; 
 alert(massive);
```

Answer (score 1):

`massive.length = 5;` вы просто создаете пустой массив длиной 5.
Чтобы еще раз присвоить необходимо сделать это явно `massive = [ 1,2,3,4,5]`

```js
let massive = [ 1,2,3,4,5]; // объявление массива и инициализация
massive.length = 0;
massive = [ 1,2,3,4,5]; 
console.log(massive);
```

`let massive` - объявление, второй раз объявлять не нужно, просто работайте с этой переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете наполнить массив элементами с помощью метода `fill()`, если необходимо наполнить массив цифрами - можете так же использовать `map()`:

```js
let massive = [ 1,2,3,4,5];

massive.length = 0;
massive = Array(5).fill(0).map((it, index) => index + 1)
console.log(massive)
```